# How do I extend Laravel Sanctum's functionality?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-airlock, laravel-sanctum

I am specifically trying to get Sanctum's Guard class to look for the API token in a JSON request body if it can't find it in the Authorization header. I simply need to add an elseif after it checks for the bearer token.

So question is: What is the best way to override this method (or class) with my own, without touching the original Sanctum files?

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Sanctum;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as AuthFactory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Guard
{
    /**
     * The authentication factory implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * The number of minutes tokens should be allowed to remain valid.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $expiration;

    /**
     * Create a new guard instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @param  int  $expiration
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(AuthFactory $auth, $expiration = null)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->expiration = $expiration;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the authenticated user for the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        if ($user = $this->auth->guard('web')->user()) {
            return $this->supportsTokens($user)
                        ? $user->withAccessToken(new TransientToken)
                        : $user;
        }

        if ($token = $request->bearerToken()) {
            $model = Sanctum::$personalAccessTokenModel;

            $accessToken = $model::where('token', hash('sha256', $token))->first();

            if (! $accessToken ||
                ($this->expiration &&
                 $accessToken->created_at->lte(now()->subMinutes($this->expiration)))) {
                return;
            }

            return $this->supportsTokens($accessToken->tokenable) ? $accessToken->tokenable->withAccessToken(
                tap($accessToken->forceFill(['last_used_at' => now()]))->save()
            ) : null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the tokenable model supports API tokens.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $tokenable
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function supportsTokens($tokenable = null)
    {
        return in_array(HasApiTokens::class, class_uses_recursive(
            $tokenable ? get_class($tokenable) : null
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've already figured out but I think you need to add an entry in your AppServiceProvider boot method and override configureGuard functionality placed in SanctumServiceProvider at line [94](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/6cce2f4dac375abf81eb7e56da48e8d3ac2734a0/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php#L94).

*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php*

```
Auth::resolved(function ($auth) {
        $auth->extend('sanctum', function ($app, $name, array $config) use ($auth) {
            return tap($this->createGuard($auth, $config), function ($guard) {
                $this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest');
            });
        });
    });
```

You will also need to override [createGuard](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/6cce2f4dac375abf81eb7e56da48e8d3ac2734a0/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php#L112) function to specify your custom Guard class with the functionality you require.